# Best practices on writing conditions in HTML tags?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

The question has surely already be asked, but I didn't find it.

I am often forced to write code like that in views:

- `<div class="<%= c ? 'my_class' : 'my_other_class' %>">`
- `<div class="<%= 'my class' if c %>">`
- `<div<%= c ? 'class="my_class"' : 'id="my_div"' %>>`

Or (the prettier way, but the less readable) :

```
<% div_inner = capture do %>
   ...
<% end %>

<% if c %>
  <div class="my_class"><%= div_inner %></div>
<% else %>
  <div><%= div_inner %></div>
<% end %>
```

A last one :

```
<% div_inner = capture do %>
   ...
<% end %>

<%= content_tag(:div, div_inner, (c ? { :class => "my_class" } : {})) %>
```

I found all this solutions syntactically dirty. I am convinced that there is a nicer way. But witch ?
Your own experiences are welcome.

Comment: Just as a note: you should add a CSS class instead of using the inline `style="display:none"`. Inline styling is generally a bad idea.

Comment: James Donnelly> Sure. The style was only here to show another example of "dirty syntax". I replace it by an id attribute, more _correct_.

Comment: A class would be more appropriate if multiple elements may end up being styled with `display:none`. IDs are unique whereas classes are not. `<div<%= c ? 'class="my_class"' : 'class="hidden"' %>>` accompanied by `.hidden { display:none; }` would be better practice than using inline styling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're correct in assuming there is a nicer way. Putting conditional logic into views is against the spirit of MVC. Based on your examples you would be fine to use a simple helper method rather than any of the more complicated implementations that you might read about around the web.

You could create a helper method that looks something like this

```
def conditional_div(condition, true_class, false_class)
  content_tag :div, class: (condition ? true_class : false_class) do
    yield if block_given?
  end
end
```

Then in your view you can use the new helper like this

```
<%= conditional_div(c, 'my_class', '') do %>
  <p>Your content</p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This is a nicer way ! I like the way you do.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a huge fan of `content_tag :div` because i find it makes the code harder to maintain and very difficult to trace. Between partials, helpers, and javascript it can take an hour to find how a class was assigned to an element.

Anyway, in the case of 
`<div class="<%= c ? 'my_class' : 'my_other_class' %>">`
I usually just try to build the class name as a property of the object. Let's say for example a label will get a different class depending on the object being **active** or **cancelled**

then my div looks like

`<div class="first-class <%= record.state %>">.....</div>`

Then my CSS has the `.active{}`, and `.cancelled{}` definitions. It doesn't get rid of all erb tags, but it definitely makes them simpler. You can end up with some odd CSS class names, but i find that easier to deal with than messy erb code.

Also this,

`<div<%= c ? 'class="my_class"' : 'id="my_div"' %>>`

just looks wrong to me. id and class are semantically different things and should not be mingled in this manner. That gets extremely difficult to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're doing, if the condition `c` is somewhat "global" (like the current page's name, or language, or whether the user is currently logged in, or whether it's morning or evening.... ), it can make sense to set these as the `body` element's CSS classes so the output looks like this:

```
<body class="is_home_page lang_en is_logged_in">
```

and to do the rest in CSS:

```
body.is_home_page .classname { color: red }
body.is_sub_page .classname { color: green }
```

that can will the overall HTML easier to read.

Comment: My question is about the syntax to use when we want to put some conditions directly in HTML tags. In other words : the conditions implies your body class will be "is_home_page" or "is_another_page".

Comment: @Forget yeah. I guess my point is that if you move this stuff to one tag, the `body`, the "how" becomes less relevant because it's only one area that you're "polluting".